# Why jquery textcomplete after first typing words can't found other words correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, utf-8, autocomplete

I use [jquery-textcomplete](https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete) for my textarea. It is work incorrect. For example first step I will type word `apple` and after add space and second way  add word `app` and this script or autocomplete can't find word `apple`. Why? How to correct it? For testing run snipped and write word `app` and showing words `app` and `apple`. Select word `apple` then add space then add also word `app` and words not be show. Then after `app` add `appe` and see to result.

```js
$('#textcomplete').textcomplete([{
  words: ['тоҷик', 'оҷиз', 'ҷило', 'тоҷ', 'тоҷикистон', 'apple', 'please', 'app', 'perl', 'person', 'erlan'],
  match: /(^|\S*)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      if (word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== 0)
        return null;

      if (term[term.length-1] === term[term.length-1].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.toLocaleUpperCase(); // last char is upper = uppercase
      if (term[0] === term[0].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + word.slice(1); // first char is upper = capitalized
        
      return word; // default; is lowercase
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textcomplete"></textarea>
```

Comment: Another example: type "app appl", the suggestion is "please".

Comment: Yes! You are right. Why it is work so incorrectly? @TakitIsy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New answer**

I don't think the beginning of your regex is necessary.
Correct me if I'm wrong, but the following works:

```js
$('#textcomplete').textcomplete([{
  words: ['тоҷик', 'оҷиз', 'ҷило', 'тоҷ', 'тоҷикистон', 'apple', 'please', 'app', 'perl', 'person', 'erlan'].sort(), // TAKIT: sort array
  match: /([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/, // TAKIT: modified here
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      if (word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== 0)
        return null;

      if (term[term.length-1] === term[term.length-1].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.toLocaleUpperCase(); // last char is upper = uppercase
      if (term[0] === term[0].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + word.slice(1); // first char is upper = capitalized
        
      return word; // default; is lowercase
    }));
  },
  index: 1, // TAKIT: modified here
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textcomplete"></textarea>
```

---

**Old answer**

*(Not working with unicode characters)*

As I am not a RegEx expert at all, I admit I don't understand exactly what the problem was.
Anyway… I used the `\b` metacharacter that matches a "word boundary" in the regex instead of `^|\S*`.
It was meant to be only a simplification, but the problem seems not to appear anymore with it:

```js
$('#textcomplete').textcomplete([{
  words: ['тоҷик', 'оҷиз', 'ҷило', 'тоҷ', 'тоҷикистон', 'apple', 'please', 'app', 'perl', 'person', 'erlan'],
  match: /(\b)([^\u0000-\u007f]{2,}|\w{2,})$/,
  search: function(term, callback) {
    callback($.map(this.words, function(word) {
      if (word.indexOf(term.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== 0)
        return null;

      if (term[term.length-1] === term[term.length-1].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.toLocaleUpperCase(); // last char is upper = uppercase
      if (term[0] === term[0].toLocaleUpperCase())
        return word.charAt(0).toLocaleUpperCase() + word.slice(1); // first char is upper = capitalized
        
      return word; // default; is lowercase
    }));
  },
  index: 2,
  replace: function(word) {
    return word + ' ';
  }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.textcomplete/1.8.4/jquery.textcomplete.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="textcomplete"></textarea>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't know but here not working unicode character words for autocomplete f.e word `тоҷик`

Comment: @Otabek You're right, `\b` won't work with unicodes. I'll look into it again.

Comment: @Otabek I've updated my answer after playing a little with the regex.

Comment: Yes your code is work @Takit Isy! Thanks ) Say please when user type words in texarea, words which found can be sorted by length?

Comment: @Otabek See my update at the end of the "words" line. :)